# Directly render and serve d3 visualizations from a nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

https://gist.github.com/Caged/6407459

I tried the above link code but it shows the following error message:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined

Can you please tell me where is the problem or any solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's a handy package for this, try `npm install d3-node`

A bunch of examples too. https://github.com/bradoyler/d3-node

Answer (score 1):

The error is comming from the line

```
d3.select('body')
```

This selection searchs in DOM an element 'body', but NodeJS does not provide a DOM. DOM is usually provided by browsers. In NodeJS you have to specify a DOM implementation.
This is explained in D3 Documentation :

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki#browser--platform-support

> D3 also runs on Node.js. Use npm install d3 to install it.
>
> Note that because Node itself lacks a DOM and multiple DOM
>   implementations exist for it (e.g., JSDOM), you'll need to explicitly
>   pass in a DOM element to your d3 methods like so:
>
> var d3 = require("d3"),
>       jsdom = require("jsdom");
>
> var document = jsdom.jsdom(),
>       svg = d3.select(document.body).append("svg");

You could try to fork this project : https://github.com/gregjopa/d3-server-side-demo.
It uses jsdom as a DOM implementation as suggested by D3 Doc.

Comment: Thanks you for reply. There is a problem: they said "Note that as of our 4.0.0 release, jsdom no longer works with Node.js™, and instead requires io.js. You are still welcome to install a release in the 3.x series if you use Node.js™."  so, I tried on 3.x series but still not working? What I suppose to do now? thanx in advance